# Fastest way to do repeated element wise matrix multiplication in MATLAB?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix-multiplication, coding-efficiency

Given a matrix `A`, I need to multiply with another constant vector `B`, N times (N > 1 million). The size of `A` is `9000x1` and `B` is `9000x1000`.

The code is currently evaluated in the following way:

```
for i=1:N

    A = func_temp(i); % A is 9000x1 matrix which varies with i

    %prod = A.*B; % prod is 9000 x 1000 matrix
    %sum_temp = sum(product); % sum_temp is 1 x 1000 matrix

    % Edit: suggestion by user @rahnema1
    sum_temp = A.' * B;

    % do multiple pperations with sum_temp

    result(i) = some_constant;
end
```

I used Profiler to see which line is taking the most time and it is the 2nd line (prod = A.*R;).
The problem is that N is very large and the code is taking over several days to complete.

I am about to try the parallel computing toolbox (GPU computing), but are there any suggestions on what I can do in the basic version?

How can I reduce the run-time of such codes in MATLAB?

Edit: I have added an edit in the code as suggested in comments which reduced run-time by 33%! But it still is the most time-taking line. Are there any more suggestions?

Comment: Use the matrix multiplication operator: `sum_temp = A.' * B;`

Comment: @rahnema1, that definitely helped. It did reduce run-time by ~33%! Can you write this as answer, so I can upvote it?

Comment: I created an answer.

Comment: Apparently, I need reputation to upvote. I will accept the answer once there can be no more improvements in the code. Thanks.

Comment: There can be no further improvements to the code, unless you specify what `func_temp()` is. If you can create a matrix for all the vectors `A`, then you can still do `A.' * B`. You want `A` to be a (>1 million)x9000 matrix, then do the matrix product `A*B`. But a large matrix like that could be slowing down your code more than the looping itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the matrix multiplication operator:

```
sum_temp = A.' * B;
```